# Struct used to extract data from firebase Real Time database no longer working (new project but same code)

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database, struct

I have a Firebase RTD setup as follows:

```
{
  "D176" : {
    "Phrase" : "Four score and seven years ago, our fore-fathers brought forth upon this continent, a new nation conceived in liberty...",
    "Version" : "Abraham Lincoln"
  },
  "D177" : {
    "Phrase" : "The acceptance of, and continuance hitherto in, the office to which your suffrages have twice called me...",
    "Version" : "George Washington"
  }
}
```

Pretty straight forward and simple set of data.  Test is the name of the parent, with a child node coded with a string such as D1, D2, D3, etc.  Within each of those child nodes are two strings coded as "P" and "V" respectively.

I have used the following struct to extract data hundreds of times without any issue:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct FavItem {
   let Phrase: String
   let Version: String

    let ref: DatabaseReference?

    
    init(Phrase: String, Version: String) {
        self.Phrase = Phrase
        self.Version = Version
        self.ref = nil
    }
    
    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        
        Phrase = snapshotValue["Phrase"] as! String
        Version = snapshotValue["Version"]  as! String
        ref = snapshot.ref
        }
        
    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "Phrase": Phrase,
            "Version": Version
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: Yes I know that Firebase declaration also includes the dB but I added it as a test and haven't removed it as of yet.

I have it defined in its own swift file aptly named "FavoriteItem.swift".

The following is the code I am using to pull the data:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      

      intArray = defaults.array(forKey: "Favorites") as? [Int] ?? []
      if intArray.count > 0 {
         let myCount = intArray.count
         for index in 1...myCount {
            myCategory = "Test/D"
            dbParm = myCategory + String(intArray[index - 1])
            print(dbParm)
            let myRef = myRef.reference(withPath: dbParm)
            myRef.keepSynced(true)
            // observe value of reference
            myRef.observe(.value, with: {
                snapshot in
                var newItems: [FavItem] = []
                for item in snapshot.children {
                  print(item)
                   let mItem = FavItem(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
                  newItems.append(mItem)

                }
                self.items = newItems
                //self.items.sort(by: {$0.key < $1.key})
                newItems = self.items
                self.tableView.reloadData()
               print(newItems)
               
            })
         }
      }
   }
```

I'm using an array built from a userdefault for the codes (D1...).

When the execution reaches let mItem = FavItem(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot) it bombs.

Error code is as follows:

> 

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1f2585b40) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1f25863d8).
2021-06-26 21:00:36.976208-0500 Bible[14649:3186734] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1f2585b40) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1f25863d8).

> 

This is the first time I have ever had this issue and frankly it baffles me, because I have used that same routine to extract data from firebase no less than 100+ times without failure.

Anyone have any idea why this would be happening? I originally had the D1, D2,... setup as an Int; changed it to a string hoping that would resolve the issue but the error is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you replace the schematic representation of your database, with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have modified the scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell your `dbParm`/`myRef` variable points to a specific child node in your JSON. For example, it can point to `D176`, which has the following JSON:

```
{
  "Phrase" : "Four score and seven years ago, our fore-fathers brought forth upon this continent, a new nation conceived in liberty...",
  "Version" : "Abraham Lincoln"
}
```

Now when you attach an observer to that JSON, you get back a snapshot of precisely the above structure. In your callback you then loop over `snapshot.children`, which means that your `item` variable is a snapshot of the individual `Phrase` or `Version` variables above, and those are simple String values - not a dictionary.

So you don't need the loop over `snapshot.children` here, since you're observing an individual `D176` node. So:

```
myRef.observe(.value, with: {
  snapshot in
    var newItems: [FavItem] = []
    let mItem = FavItem(snapshot: snapshot)
    newItems.append(mItem)
```

Comment: Duh, I must be dense as a brick.  Thanks Frank, I appreciate the help and guidance.